# Funciones del subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

Me gustaría saber vuestra opinión acerca de la función del subjuntivo en una frase.

Mi profe nos ha enseñado que en oraciones sustantivas se distinguen tres tipos de funciones del subjuntivo:

**subjuntivo volitivo** (el verbo de la oración principal expresa deseo, prohibición, permiso, órden, consejo, etc.)

**dubitativo** (el hablante pone en duda lo de que se trata en la oración subordinada: *no es cierto, no estoy seguro, dudo que …, supondo que* …, etc.)

**temático** (el verbo de la oración principal expresa evaluación o emociones tipo *me alegro …, estoy contento … , temo …,* etc.)

Aquí tengo una frase:

> (1) Y ahora **imagínate** **que** Hitler **hubiese nacido** en los Estados Unidos.

Según la lista de los verbos y expresiones que tengo aquí, el verbo de la principal *imaginar* pertenece a la clase de los verbos y expresiones dubitativos ya que el hablante pone en duda el contenido de la oración subordinada.

cf. *"Es difícil imaginar que se pueda llegar a estos números"
"No puedo imaginar que esto pueda ser organizado por alguien"*

Pero creo que en (1) el subjuntivo en la oración subordinada no tiene valor dubitativo porque no evalúa el valor de verdad sino el hablante pide al oyente que se imagine una situación irreal, entonces se trata de una situación contrafactual (si parafraseamos la frase, tenemos *Y ahora imagínate lo que habría pasado si Hitler hubiese nacido en los Estados Unidos*.)

Antes de presentar mi opinión a mi profesor me gustaría preguntaros si lo que pienso suena razonable o si es una tontería. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El subjuntivo tiene muchas más funciones, pero no todas son fáciles de explicar o de justificar. Está bien que el profesor te las muestre así, pero al final el subjuntivo se aprende encontrándolo en diferentes patrones de uso, no pensando dónde encaja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Cómo clasificarías las siguientes frases?

> (2) Dudo que Hitler haya nacido en los Estados Unidos.
>
> (3) No creo que Hitler haya nacido en los Estados Unidos.

Dubitativo, ¿no?  Y también tu frase (1).  Es que "dubitativo" es una categoría más amplia de lo que tú pensabas, creo.

No recuerdo exactamente cómo se categorizaban los usos del subjuntivo cuando estudié el español, pero creo que no era un sistema tan rígido y simple.

Si tú quieres hacer una cuarta categoría para ti, está bien.  O podrías modificar la definición (o descripción) de la categoría "dubitativa" para ti misma.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas! 
@aparente001: en mi opinión (2) y (3) claramente tienen el valor dubitatito... me gustaría saber cómo ves tú lo de „una subordinada condicional oculta“ (la respuesta de FGSUZ)

Comment: @Aurora - si me permites, voy a expresar la frase original en inglés: *Now, imagine that Hitler had been born in the U.S.*; si cambio la frase un poco: *Now imagine that Hitler were alive in 19xx etc.*  Esto es el subjuntivo también; así que yo pienso que no es necesario cambiar el "que" por "si."

Comment: ah sí, ahora entiendo, muchas gracias : )

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas el presente de indicativo "imagínate que ha nacido y ...", a partir del "que" ya te has trasladado a la narración de una historia, en la que se usa el presente como variación estilística de la narración. Es un recurso, pero como ves, suena raro.

... y es debido a que lo que realmente tienes es una **subordinada condicional** oculta, que en lugar de con un "si" comienza con un "que", pero es lo mismo. Es como decir "imagínate qué pasaría SI Hitler hubiese nacido". Ahí claramente tenemos la subordinada condicional, que rige subjuntivo.